# How to display a color map as pygame surface generated from an array in real-time?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygame

My goal is to display inside a pygame instance a color map reflecting a real-time input in form of a 49 elements ndarray, ranging from -6 to 2, normalized into values ranging from 0 to 1. As of now, I was creating the map with matplotlib and using a backend to convert it to a rgb string to finally get my pygame surface. My main issue was a really slow display (approximately 1 fps), so I decided to directly generate this map as a pygame surface, but I am struggling to find a satisfying display.

How could I generate a pygame surface from an array in real-time and scale it to a reasonable size to obtain a display close to what I got with matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you can render an array with pygame. I don't have an idea what is matplotlib and what calculations you need to do, so I answer two last question. To scale the Surface you use pygame.transform.scale function (see docs). As for array rendering, briefly, you need Numpy and pygame libraries installed of course. Then you decide where and what data goes. Normally in surfaces you have color channels - Red Green Blue and Alpha (if you use transparency). There you should write your data. See the following example, it just put rectangles in channel arrays and draws it to the screen (just once, without any changes).

```
import numpy, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# byte packing function
def Pack4bytes(c1,c2,c3,c4) :
    result = c1 << 24 | c2 << 16 | c3 << 8 | c4
    return result

#Initialise display and empty array
width = 200
height = 100
pygame.init()
DISP = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
Sample = numpy.zeros((width, height), dtype = numpy.uint32)
Output = numpy.zeros_like(Sample)

#Initialise color channels
A = numpy.zeros_like(Sample)
R = numpy.zeros_like(Sample)
G = numpy.zeros_like(Sample)
B = numpy.zeros_like(Sample)

def Render() :
    # for example, fill the channels with some data
    # note the index order - pygame treats array as transposed matrix
    # first index refers to X , second - to Y coordinate
    R[:, 20:30] = 127
    G[:, 40:50] = 127
    B[:, 60:70] = 127

    # Now pack data and blit
    # Note byte order - in pygame it is exactly as follows - ARGB
    Output = Pack4bytes(A,R,G,B) 
    # blit Output to display, this one is for output same size as display
    pygame.surfarray.blit_array(DISP, Output) 

MyLoop = True
FPS = 8
clock = pygame.time.Clock( ) 
Render()
# empty loop, just does nothing
while MyLoop:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get( ):
        if event.type == QUIT: MyLoop = False
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE: MyLoop = False
    pygame.display.update( )
pygame.quit( )
```

Read the comments in Render function carefully, it is very important. So if you need a changing picture, just place the call of Render() inside the loop and define what calculation you want to do in function body. This example is for RGB only, so Alpha will be just ignored. Tested with Python 2.6.6 and Numpy 1.5.1